# uibinder css literal Hide options

Tags: css, gwt, internet-explorer-6, uibinder

Inside my CSS, I put:

```
.someClass {
  width: literal("expression(this.width > 40 ? 40: true)");
}
```

Is this correct syntax? I tried, but no result output when I debug with Firebug on Firefox. I'm trying to make max-width work in IE6.

Comment: I don't know much about the literal function (the docs are pretty light: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource#Literal_function) but I don't think you can reference `this` in them, just the document, etc.

Comment: Your conditional expression seems to be wrong, BTW. It should be something like `this.width > 40 ? 40 : this.width` (at least, that's the syntax for these sort of expressions in C++/Java).

Comment: ya. i did testing    expression(this.width) seem not supported in gwt uibinder

Comment: any workaround for "this" keyword.  gwt uibinder css not support it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be helpful for achieving max-width with ie6: http://www.svendtofte.com/code/max_width_in_ie/

Comment: the article didnt mentioned about this.width  . and the article only guide on setting entire clientWidth . i only want to set maxwidth for one html element

Comment: yeah true, sorry. did you try the workaround with 'document.getElementById('id').offsetWidth' instead of 'this'? btw: did you submit this issue? http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5337

Answer (score 1):

this may be a case for doing this outside of the CSS, in JavaScript. Or if you're doing a lot of DOM manipulation then maybe consider using jQuery.